# Rewrite rule for url containing Id

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

How can we redirect all the requests coming to:

https://www.example.com/url/sub/string-string2-58

To this url:

https://www.example.com/newurl/string-string2/58

Basically we have to split the last part with regex and get the last term as id and redirect to a new structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="sub id redirect" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
     <add input="{URL}" pattern="/string-string2-([0-9]+)" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample1.com/newurl/string-string2/{C:1}" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa.

Comment: not the actual answer I was expected but it will show the brief way to the people looking for a solution